# Create sorted dictionary from dictionary in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I'm trying to adapt code written in C# into a vb.net application. At one point a variable of type Dictionary is converted to a variable of type SortedDictionary.  I've re-written it in vb.net, but it throws an error.  What needs to change for this code to work in vb.net?

Here's the original c# code:

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("x-amz-date", requestMoment.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
headers.Add("x-amz-access-token", txtOAuthToken.Text);
headers.Add("host", "sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com");
SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedHeaders = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(headers);
```

Here's my vb.net code:

```
Dim headers = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
headers.Add("x-amz-date", requestMoment.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"))
headers.Add("x-amz-access-token", gblOAuthToken)
headers.Add("host", "sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com")
Dim sortedHeaders As SortedDictionary(Of String, String) = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)(headers)
```

The c# works fine.  In the vb.net code, the last line throws this error

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
> 'Public Overloads Sub New(dictionary As IDictionary(Of String, String))': Argument matching parameter 'dictionary' narrows from 'Object' to 'IDictionary(Of String, String)'.
> 'Public Overloads Sub New(comparer As IComparer(Of String))': Argument matching parameter 'comparer' narrows from 'Object' to 'IComparer(Of String)'.

Comment: Do you have [`Option Infer On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement)? Why not?

Comment: @GSerg It's off by default, so it's safe to assume OP is not using infer.  Given that, `headers` should be declared as `Dim headers as Dictionary` as otherwise it gets a type of `Object`, which confuses the overload resolution.  Either that or explicitly cast `headers` to `IDictionary` in the `SortedDictionary` constructor.

Comment: Just declare the Dictionary as `Dim headers As IDictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()`. Or `Dim headers As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()`. Set all `Options` to `On`, C# style. You're good.

Comment: @GSerg Setting infer on fixed the issue.  Can you explain what this does and why it's needed in vb.net and not in C#?  I'm mainly a C# programmer, but this is an old company application written in vb.net.  Thank you for you help!

Comment: @boilers222 What it does you can see by clicking the link in my comment. It's needed in VB.NET because VB.NET is relaxed about types by default unlike C# where `var` always works like `Dim` with `Infer On`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting "infer on" at the very top of the class, before the Import statements, fixed the problem for me.

```
 Option Infer On
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make sense to me to bother with the dictionary:

```
Dim sortedHeaders As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
sortedHeaders.Add("x-amz-date", requestMoment.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"))
sortedHeaders.Add("x-amz-access-token", gblOAuthToken)
sortedHeaders.Add("host", "sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com")
```